# Can I trust Django's bulk_create to preserve order?

Tags: django

When I do something like this:

```
model_list = [Model(name = 'First'), Model(name = 'Second'), Model(name = 'Third')]
Model.objects.bulk_create(model_list)
```

Can I trust that they will be created in that same order?

That is:

```
pk1 = Model.objects.get(name = 'First').pk
pk2 = Model.objects.get(name = 'Second').pk
pk3 = Model.objects.get(name = 'Third').pk

(pk3 > pk2) and (pk2 > pk1)
```

Comment: I would think so, but I don't know the answer to this off the top of my head and I'm on mobile, but in the future questions like this would probably be answered quicker on irc in#django on freenode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can trust according to the documentation for Django 4.2 here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create:

> This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are), and returns created objects as a list, in the same order as provided...

Answer (score 4):

I think you can.

```
model_list = [Model(name = 'First'),
              Model(name = 'Second'),
              Model(name = 'Third')]
Model.objects.bulk_create(model_list)
```

This code will be translated to the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO app_model (name) VALUES ('First'), ('Second'), ('Third')
```

It is very unlikely that regular SQL server will insert these rows in different order.

Comment: Can you please explain why there is a probabilistic element? Why is it 'highly unlikely' that it will insert the rows in that order rather than 'it will never happen'?